# What is the best way to update more than 1 million rows in a table in Oracle using a CSV file

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am trying to update only one column of the 1 million records in a table based on the value in the CSV file.

Sample CSV file:

`1,Apple
2,Orange
3,Mango`

The first column in the file is the PK I will use to filter the record and the second column is the new value of the column in the table I want to update.The PK in the CSV file may or may not exist in the DB though. I was thinking of creating a script to make a million update statements based on the file. I would like to know if there are any better way on how could I do this?

Comment: I would load it into a new table and just swap the table names afterwards, or do some partition switching trick

Answer (score 3):

personally i would

1. load the CSV file into a new table using sqlldr
2. make sure the correct indexes are on the new and existing table
3. write ONE update statement to update the existing table from the new
   one

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. Create an [external table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i) using the csv
2. Update existing table from the new external table in just one update